# Custom post type Shortcodes wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I want to Add slider shortcodes. My all slider fields adds properly in shortcode, but the read more button and button link is not displaying. Can you please solve my problem?
This my slider code:

```php
<section id="firstsection">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12 firstsection-maindiv">
            <?php 
                $slide = array( 'post_type' => 'slider' ,);
                $slider_query = new WP_Query( $slide );
            ?>
            <?php 
                if( have_posts() ) : while($slider_query->have_posts() ) : $slider_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div id="explore-section" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xs-12  firstsection-innerdiv">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 firstsection-inner-left-div">
                            <p class="oneplace"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>
                            <p class="slider-content"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
                            <?php $buttonname = get_post_meta($post->ID, "wp_producer_name" , true) ?>
                            <?php $buttonlink = get_post_meta($post->ID, "wp_button_link" , true) ?>
                            <button class="slider-btn" type="button"><a href="<?php echo $buttonlink ; ?>"> <?php echo $buttonname ; ?></a></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6   firstsection-inner-right-div">
                     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail();  ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
  </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And this is my shortcodes code:

```php
// Add Shortcode
add_shortcode( 'valute-slider-shortcode', 'display_custom_post_type' );
function display_custom_post_type(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'Slider',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $string = '';
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        $string .= '<section id="firstsection">';
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();


             $buttonname = get_post_meta($post->ID, "wp_producer_name" , true);
           
            if( !empty($buttonname) ): endif;  
         
            $string .= '<div class="container-fluid">'  . 
                            '<div class="col-xs-12 firstsection-maindiv">' .
                            '<div id="explore-section" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">' . 
                                '<div class="item">' . 
                                    '<div class="col-xs-12  firstsection-innerdiv">' .
                                    ' <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 firstsection-inner-left-div">' .
                                        ' <p class="oneplace">'  .get_the_title() . '</p>'.
                                        ' <p class="slider-content">'  .get_the_content()  . '</p>'.
                                           ' <button class="slider-btn" type="button">' . $buttonname . '</button>'.
                                    '</div>' . ' <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6   firstsection-inner-right-div">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>' .
                                    '</div>' . 
                                '</div>' .
                            '</div>' .
                         '</div>';
        }
        $string .= '</section>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $string;
```

Comment: Hi sir have you any idea o solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`

This will fix your problem

Comment: Thank You Sir its working

Answer (score 0):

You're using this to get the post ID:

```php
             $buttonname = get_post_meta($post->ID, "wp_producer_name" , true);
```

But what is `$post`? PHP has never seen this before in this scope, so it resolves to an empty value, undefined/null/0. In order to use global variables, you have to declare them before using them.

So there are 2 alternatives:

- `global $post;`
- `get_the_ID()`

Comment: Ok sir, Thanks for sharing with me this useful information.